# ChromeOS Filesystem Provider and large files

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I am working on a provider and I have a problem with large resources. I do not want to store them in memory, but the REST API I am using doesn't so I thought I could try to cache the file locally.  The thing is I cannot find a way to create a temporary file on the local filesystem.  On normal Linux I would create something in `/var/cache` but that doesn't seem to work here.  Is there a way to create a local temp file that can go away when my session ends?

Comment: The only such thing is string-based sessionStorage with a limit of 5-10MB. You'll have to use it or chrome.storage.local, IndexedDB, localStorage. Chrome also still supports HTML5 FileSystem.

Comment: I was looking at the HTML5 FileSystem, I just didn't know where I could store the temp files.  Something like `mksemp(3)` would be great.

Comment: That API has its own syntax described in the tutorial. The files are stored in your browser profile directory.

Comment: Okay, I will give that a try!

Answer (score 0):

by design, CrOS apps/extensions do not get access to filesystem paths (e.g. /var).  that would violate the security model.

you can use the web [FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) in order to get a pseudo filesystem you can access.  Chrome will take care of the actual storage on disk, so you only worry about accessing it through the JS APIs.

there are other storage APIs available, but i think the FileSystem API is the only one that can handle "large resources" as you describe.  this old (but largely still relevant) article discusses the different storage options:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/